# Im having problems with displaying a BufferedImage along with text fields on a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, bufferedimage

So the program I am working on takes in an image, compresses it and sends it to a JPEG. I have the program working fine and I am just trying to make it look nice. I am doing this through Java Swing, which I am a complete novice at.

Here is my main:

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.RenderedImage;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;
import javax.imageio.IIOImage;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.imageio.ImageWriteParam;    
import javax.imageio.ImageWriter;
import javax.imageio.stream.FileImageOutputStream;
import javax.imageio.stream.ImageOutputStream;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;

import com.sun.media.jai.widget.DisplayJAI;


public class JPEGCompression {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
    chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File("./tmp"));

    chooser.setFileFilter(new javax.swing.filechooser.FileFilter() {
        public boolean accept(File f) {
            return f.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".png")
                    || f.isDirectory();
        }

        public String getDescription() {
            return "PNG Images";
        }
    });

    int r = chooser.showOpenDialog(new JFrame());
    if (r == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        BufferedImage n = ImageIO.read(chooser.getSelectedFile());
        showOriginalImage("Original Image", n);
        compressAndShow(n, 0.7f);

    }

}

public static void compressAndShow(BufferedImage image, float quality)
        throws IOException {

    Iterator<ImageWriter> writers = ImageIO.getImageWritersBySuffix("jpeg");
    if (!writers.hasNext())
        throw new IllegalStateException("No writers found");
    ImageWriter writer = (ImageWriter) writers.next();

    ImageWriteParam param = writer.getDefaultWriteParam();
    param.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);
    param.setCompressionQuality(quality);

    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 
    ImageOutputStream ios = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(bos);
    writer.setOutput(ios);
    writer.write(null, new IIOImage(image, null, null), param);
    ios.flush();

    ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(bos.toByteArray());
    RenderedImage out = ImageIO.read(in);
    int size = bos.toByteArray().length;
    showCompressedImage("Compressed to " + quality + ": " + size + " bytes", out);

    File file = new File("compressed. " + quality + ".jpeg");
    FileImageOutputStream output = new FileImageOutputStream(file);
    writer.setOutput(output);
    writer.write(null, new IIOImage(image, null, null), param);

}

private static void showOriginalImage(String title, RenderedImage img) {


    JFrame frame = new JFrame(title);
    frame.getContentPane().add(new DisplayJAI(img));
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

}

private static void showCompressedImage(String title, RenderedImage img) {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame(title);
    frame.getContentPane().add(new DisplayJAI(img));
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

}
```

}

The two show image methods are identical at the moment. What I want is the showOriginalImage() to have a text field at the top of the frame where the user can input the compression quality (at the moment it is hard coded as 0.7f) with a value between 0-1. Then once they have chosen the quality, compressAndShow() will run.

Any advice/help on how I would go about doing this would be greatly appreciated,
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a JPanel and add both the DisplayJAI and JTextField to it. Then add this panel to the content pane. It may be that the default panel layout (FlowLayout) is not appropriate for your needs. In this case, try using [BorderLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/BorderLayout.html) or [BoxLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/BoxLayout.html).